# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in React when dispatching a login function

Tags: javascript

I'm following a tutorial and I'm stuck on this error that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to dispatch parameters to a login function in AuthActions.js but I keep getting the error **TypeError: Object(...) is not a function** when I submit. My code is below

This is the code in AuthActions.js

```
    export const login = (email, pass) => {
            return {
                type: 'LOGIN',
                payload: {email, pass}
            }
        }
```

Then in this is the code in the login component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Field from "../Field";
import {login} from "../../store/actions/AuthActions";

const fields = [
    {label: 'Username/Email', placeholder: 'Enter Your Username/Email', elementName: 'input', type: 'email', name: 'email', id: 'user'},
    {label: 'Password', placeholder: 'Enter Your Password', elementName: 'input', type: 'password', name: 'password', id: 'password'}
]

class Login extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='col-lg-8 mx-auto'>
                <form onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.props.login(this.props.values.email, this.props.values.password);
                }}>
                    {fields.map((field, fieldIndex) => {
                        return(
                            <Field
                                {...field}
                                key={fieldIndex}
                                value={this.props.values[field.name]}
                                name={field.name}
                                onChange={this.props.handleChange}
                                onBlur = {this.props.handleBlur}
                                touched = {(this.props.touched[field.name])}
                                errors = {(this.props.errors[field.name])}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                    }
                    <br/>
                    <div id='success'/>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <button className='btn btn-primary btn-l'>Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        //this is where the error point to
        login: (email, pass) => dispatch(login(email, pass))
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

It throws this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    login Login.js:71
    onSubmit Login.js:30
    React 17
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:653
    React 4
```

On this function

```
login: (email, pass) => dispatch(login(email, pass))
```

This is the reducer too

```
const defaultState = {
    user: {},
    token: null
}

const auth = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LOGIN':
            return{
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
                token: 1
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default auth
```

Comment: Welcome @Kingsley to Stack Overflow. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to see how to ask a question. Please remove the other unnecessary details and paste a minimal reproducible code. In addition to this, please show the logs of your functions.

Comment: @ShivamSingla have I fixed it now?

Comment: @KingsleyDGyekye Can you share your reducer as well?

Comment: @jzProg I've done that now

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working. (I used exactly your reducer and action)

```
class Login extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='col-lg-8 mx-auto'>
            <label>{ this.props.auth?.user.email }</label>
            <button onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.props.login('email', 'password');
            }}>CLICK</button>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        //this is where the error point to
        login: (email, pass) => dispatch(login(email, pass))
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

If you have done it by combining your reducers:
e.g

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authed from './authed';

export default combineReducers({
  authed,
})
```

You should change your `mapStateToProps` as below:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state.authed
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I was still getting the error. I can't what exactly I changed in the code but it's working now after I restarted the whole project

Comment: mm weird because i couldn't re-produce your issue.That line was ok. Anyway, it's great you found a solution!